# scoping concern when dealing with coupling

Tags: design, object-oriented, ruby

I'm learning ruby (and OOP in the process) and I find keep having to write the same patterns when logging progress so I want to wrap this up in a logging library that my other code can then just pass data to - say a string, a file name and a log level. This of course couples the logging library with other code - other code still has to be aware of how the logging library works (that it wants the string, name, & level). I tend not to like coupling like this but it seems like I can't really prevent it, but rather have to deal with it by consciously deciding to scope the library's use to an area of concern "ie: snoweagle's personal tech projects"

Is this good design or is there a better way to approach coupling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you're describing is *necessarily* tightly coupled

> This of course couples the logging library with other code - other code still has to be aware of how the logging library works (that it wants the string, name, & level)

Not exactly.  The consuming code won't need to know *how* the logging library works.  It'll simply need to know *what is expected* of a logging library.  In other words, consuming code only needs to know about the logging library's **public interface**.

If your language supports it, you can guarantee looser coupling by forcing the consuming code to work against a Logger Interface (as opposed to the Logger implementation).

This is considered loosely coupled because there is only one --clearly defined-- point of contact between the Logger library and the consuming code.  This is the Logger Interface.

If in the future you decided to swap out your Logger for a new-fangled modern logger, then all you would need to do is code a compatibility layer between your new Logger lib and your existing Logger Interface.  Loose coupling to the max ;)

In C#:

Your logger interface:

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void Log(String filename, String message, Level level);
    void Log(String filename, Exception exception, Level level);
    void Log(String message, Level level);
    void Log(Exception exception, Level level);
    void LogInfo(String message);
    void LogWarning(String message);
    void LogError(String error);
    void LogError(Exception error);
    // etc...
}
```

A specific implementation of `ILogger`

```
public class AbcLogger : ILogger
{
    // Implements all of ILogger

    public void LogWarning(String message)
    {
        this.abcTarget.Write(message, AbcLevelsEnum.Warning)
    }
}
```

Code consuming a Logger

```
public void SomeMethod(int a)
{
    if (a < 1000)
    {
        String message = "Quantities of fewer than 1000 bananas are not accepted";

        ILogger logger = ServiceLocator.GetMeMyLogger();
        logger.LogWarning(message);

        throw new BananaException(message);
    }

    // do more...
}
```

As you can see, the consuming code isn't aware it's dealing with `AbcLogger`.  All it knows is that a logger is available and that it can be used by going throw the `ILogger` interface.

And this way, if you ever want to switch to another logger like this one...

```
public class XyzLogger : ILogger
{
    // Implements all of ILogger

    public void LogWarning(String message)
    {
        this.xyzTarget.Flush();
        this.xyzTarget.OtherPreRequisites();

        this.xyzTarget.Write(message, XyzLevel.NonCritical)

        this.xyzTarget.Flush();
        this.xyzTarget.OtherPostRequisites();
    }
}
```

...it's just a matter of changing your application's bootstrapping code to use `XyzLogger` instead of `AbcLogger`.

```
public Bootstrapping()
{
    ServiceLocator.SetLogger(new XyzLogger());
    ServiceLocator.SetBananaManager(new BananaManaga());
    // ... etc
}
```